# kubectl after device login returns error you must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

What works on one corporate computer doesn't work on another.

Maybe corporate network proxy or CA cert? Domain whitelisting? How do you debug this?

```
az login
az account set --subscription <subscription>
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <group name> --name <aks name>
kubectl get nodes
```

To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code ... to authenticate.
E1201 ...  11576 round_trippers.go:174] CancelRequest not implemented by *azure.azureRoundTripper
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Comment: Do you log in via the Azure CLI when you use another computer with the same account?

Comment: yes, as shown above, az login, setting the subscription, then getting credentials with the az aks get-credentials command

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted to open an Azure support ticket, it alerted  that there were failures because of using an old kubectl CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that the version of "Docker for Mac" I was using was overriding the `kubectl` installation I had done via `homebrew.

```sh
❯ which kubectl
/usr/local/bin/kubectl
❯ ls -l /usr/local/bin/kubectl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  55 16 Sep  2019 /usr/local/bin/kubectl -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl
```

And when I checked the version of the client, sure enough:

```sh
kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14" //snip
```

This seems to have been resolved quite some time ago, but may save some time for someone in the future

The solutions seem to be:

1. Upgrade docker for mac (if this is your problem)
2. Delete the link to the docker for mac provided `kubectl` and set to a current version